# How to deduce derivative $dy/dx$

Tags: derivatives

Given this equation:

$\frac{dv}{dt} = - \lambda \frac{y}{x}$ where $\lambda$ is a real constant

$y = v - \alpha$

$x = \beta + \lambda t$

How do we deduce that $\frac{dy}{dx} = -\frac{y}{x}~ ?$

Comment: It's very difficult to solve your problem because there are not enough details. If you have variables $v$ and $t$ on one side, nobody can really work out why your second equation is $dy \over dx$.

Comment: How are $v,t$ and $y,x$ related? Please edit your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> $\frac{dv}{dt} = - \lambda \frac{y}{x}$ where $\lambda$ is a real constant

> $y = v - \alpha$

> $x= \beta + \lambda t$

Assume $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are independent of $t$

$$\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{dy}{dt}\frac{dt}{dx}=\frac{dv}{dt}\cdot \frac{1}\lambda=-\lambda\frac{y}{x}\cdot\frac{1}\lambda=-\frac{y}{x}$$